# Draw image on canvas with the Retina display

Tags: ios, html, canvas, cordova, retina-display

It is a web App in phonegap 
I have used a 320 by 480 image to draw but it fuzzy.

html

```
<canvas id="canvas" height=480 width=320>
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(images[index],0,0,320,480);
```

How to draw clearly on the retina display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to a larger versions of your images, you can double the visible resolution.

The source images would need to be 640x960:

This is the code to "pixel double" the resolution of an image.

```
canvas.width = 640;
canvas.height = 960;
canvas.style.width = "320px";
canvas.style.height = "480px";
```

If not, you could use the same "pixel doubling" effect and present a smaller but clearer version using your existing images:

```
canvas.width = 320;
canvas.height = 480;
canvas.style.width = "160px";
canvas.style.height = "240px";
```

Comment: MarkE is right, just don't forget to adjust your input values too, they're relative to the retina size!

Answer (score 1):

#### This is a general answer on how to draw (anything) on canvas to make it look sharp on retina displays or any high DPI display.

Get the screen density with:

```
var screenDensity = window.devicePixelRatio
```

Then just multiply your path, stroke, font size, canvas size, etc. with `screenDensity`.

Exaple:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var screenDensity = window.devicePixelRatio;

// Make it visually fill the positioned parent
canvas.style.width = '100%';
canvas.style.height = '100%';
// ...then set the internal size to match
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * screenDensity;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * screenDensity;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(42 * screenDensity, 0);
ctx.lineTo(42 * screenDensity, 4 * screenDensity);
// (...more stuff goes here...)
ctx.closePath();
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.lineWidth = 2 * screenDensity;
ctx.stroke();
```

---

Alternatively, you can set the canvas `scale` to `screenDensity`. See here for more info and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio